# Is this $\large \in$ $|$ $\large =$ exchange naive set theory consistent?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, alternative-set-theories

This question is more of a trick.

Notation: for any formula $\phi$, let $\phi^=$ mean the formula obtained by *merely* replacing each occurrence of the membership symbol $\in$ in $\phi$ by the equality symbol $=$, so for example if $\phi$ is the formula $(y \in y)$, then $\phi^=$ is the formula $(y=y)$.

We assume full Extensionality throughout this exposition.

Notice this *naive* like **Comprehension axiom scheme**:

If $\phi$ is a formula in the first order language of set theory (i.e.; $\sf FOL(=,\in)$), in which the symbol $``x"$ doesn't occur free, then: $$[\exists y (\phi^=) \wedge \exists y ((\neg \phi)^=) \to \exists x \forall y (y \in x \iff \phi)]$$; is an axiom.

**Axiom of Multiplicity:** $\exists x,y: x \neq y $

This theory supply the appearance of an inconsistent theory. However, a proof of this inconsistency keeps eluding me?!

> Is this theory consistent?

The point is that this theory is *very* naive. The antecedent of comprehension is an extremely simple syntactical procedure, more of a trick really! In other words its a very naive kind of restriction on the original unrestricted naive comprehension.

The general expectation for such maneuvers is inconsistency!?

This theory [if consistent] has a universal set. So if consistent, it might be interpretable in one of the fragments of $\sf NF$? It would be nice to see if that is the case!

Comment: Since for all x, x not in x, the replacement gives for all x, x /= x.

Comment: @WilliamElliot, you mean if $\phi$ is the formula $(\forall x (x \not \in x))$ then $\phi^=$ is the formula $\forall x (x \neq x)$; yes that is correct! Notice that this is just a definition of a syntactical procedure, its NOT to be understood as stipulating axioms, i.e. it does NOT mean that if $\phi$ is an axiom then $\phi^=$ is an axiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a model: $\{1,2\}$ with $$ 1\in 1 \qquad 1\notin 2 \qquad 2\in 2 \qquad 2\notin 1 $$

That is, two Quine atoms side by side in an otherwise empty world.

In this model $\in$ and $=$ behave identically, so $\phi^=\leftrightarrow \phi$. Thus, the antecedent of your comprehension axiom demands that there is a $y$ that satisfies $\phi$ and another $y$ that doesn't satisfy $\phi$, which means that the collection you're looking for is either $\{1\}$ or $\{2\}$, which are exactly the options you have.

(Note that this model does *not* have a universal set).

---

That is the **only** model, though. If you strengthen your multiplicity axiom such that it promises *three* distinct sets $a,b,c$, then the following loophole will give unrestricted comprehension, and therefore an inconsistent theory:

The restricted comprehension axiom allows you to form $\{a,b\}$ -- because there is now a $c$ such that $\neg(c=a\lor c=b)$ -- and this unordered pair cannot equal both $a$ and $b$ at the same time, so there are *some* sets $p,q$ such that $p\in q$ but $p\ne q$.

Now to form unrestricted $\{y\mid \psi(y)\}$, use your comprehension axiom with a parameter $a$ and
$$ \phi \equiv (\forall p,q(p\in q\leftrightarrow p=q)\land y=a) \lor
(\neg \forall p,q(p\in q\leftrightarrow p=q) \land \psi(y)) $$

Comment: @Zuhair: Indeed. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: It appears that one can remedy this by requiring that every subformula $\psi(y)$of the formula $\phi$ [having no parameters other than those of $\phi$], must obey the antecedent of comprehension. And of course upgrade the multiplicity axiom to assert existence of 3 distinct sets.

Comment: @Zuhair: That would, among other restrictions, require every atomic formula to be either $a\in y$ or $y\in a$ or $y=a$ for some variable or parameter $a$. That sounds quite limiting, worse than NF. (And how do you deal with variables that are bound by quantifiers inside $\phi$?)

Comment: If I put $\phi$ in Prenex normal form, then would the same hold. I tend to think so. If so then this would escape even my recent restrictions on subformulas.